# Solution of a System of Equation through Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 4}$. Suppose I am also given $$Ax = \begin{bmatrix}5 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix},$$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 1}.$

To find the solution would I just make an augmented matrix and perform Gaussian Elimination to get the solution?

Also what does it mean to put the solution in the form
$$v_p + c_1v_1 + c_1v_2 + \ldots + c_nv_n $$

Comment: I don't know the notation you have at the end but I assume it means write the solution as the sum $x_{\textrm{particular}}$ and $x_{\textrm{homogeneous}}$. The particular solution is the solution to $Ax=b$ and the homogeneous solution is a solution to $Ax=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for your first question.

For your second question $v_p$ is a particular solution to the system.

For $i=1,\ldots, n$, $v_i$ are solutions to $$Ax= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

and $c_i$ are arbitary constants.

$$A\left(v_p+\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i\right)=Av_p+\sum_{i=1}^nc_iAv_i=Av_p$$